# DataTables gives warning if there is an empty cell

Tags: javascript, datatables

DataTables alerts me if there is an empty cell in my table. Here is the warning:

> Requested unknown parameter 'Description' for row 1.

My code is here:

```
var columns = [

    {
       mDataProp: 'Description',
       sTitle: 'Description'             
    },
    //
    // other columns 
    //
];

 var dt = $('#myDataTable').dataTable({
        sAjaxSource: '/JobScheduler/GetJobs',
        bServerSide: true,
        fnServerData: function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {

            $(aoData).each(function(i, o){
                var params = o.name.split('_');
                if (params[0] == 'mDataProp')
                {
                    var value = $.grep(aoData, function(e){ return e.name == "sSearch_" + params[1]; })[0].value;

                    if (value != "")
                    {
                        aoData.push({ name: o.value, value: value });
                    }
                }
            });

            $.getJSON(sSource, aoData, function (data) {
                if (isSuccess(data)) {
                    fnCallback(data.message);
                } else {
                    showMessage(data);
                }
            });
        },
        bProcessing: true,
        sDom: 'T<"new">Rrlptip',
        fnRowCallback: function (nRow, aData) {
            nRow.setAttribute('id', aData['JobId']);
        },
        aoColumns: columns
})
```

What should I do to prevent this warning? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your header table has more column than the data itself

Comment: Nope, when I fill all cells of the Description table, I m not facing a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your columns and add a [`defaultContent`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.defaultContent) option for the one(s) causing you issues.

Something like this:

```
...
{
   mDataProp: 'YourData',
   sTitle: 'YourDescription',
   sDefaultContent: ''
},
...
```

Comment: I want to leave it empty, if there is not data for the cell. Isn't it possible?

Comment: Can you please include a code block for completeness?

Comment: Useful for me too.
"columns": [
                   { "data": "id",  sDefaultContent: '' },
 ]
I added like this